# Reloading model in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want get some qualification about reloading model in mvc action. For example:

I have some class model:

```
public class PresentationItemModel()
{   
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Type { get; set; }
   public List<int> PresentationIdList { get; set; }
}
```

And some controller action:

```
public ActionResult PostAction(PresentationItemModel model)
{
   ...

   if(model.PresentationIdList == null)
   {
      model.PresentationIdList = new List<int>();
   }
   model.PresentationIdList.Add(model.Id);

   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

I can call **PostAction** method several times and I want to save **model.PresentationIdList** result with all id's. But every time my PresentationIdList reloading with all model. But it's standard behavior.

Can I resolve it?

Comment: I understand that English might not be your first language, but try to reword your question a little bit to make it more clear. I'll keep looking at it to try and come up with an answer.

Comment: Your `PostAction` accepts a new `PresentationItemModel` each time. So if you want to store `id`s on each POST you should store them in a database.

Comment: This code is a piece from my project. And I shouldn't save to db. In lates logic I do it, but I want to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is return the `model` object from your `PostAction`:

```
public ActionResult PostAction(PresentationItemModel model)
{
   ...

   if(model.PresentationIdList == null)
   {
      model.PresentationIdList = new List<int>();
   }
   model.PresentationIdList.Add(model.Id);

   ...
   ...
   ...

   return new ActionResult(model);
}
```